# saving input and output in R

Tags: r

I am taking a class in linear regression and we are using R Studio. This is my first time being introduced to a program like this.

I am trying to save my input AND output (preferably together). I have tried several different packages and methods, but it is not what I'm looking for. I was hoping to save my work like this: (example)

http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~nasser/Teaching/STAT462_862/LDA_QDA.pdf

If anyone can help me, I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re looking for R Markdown: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com

It lets you mix formatted text and r code and can export a full document with figures and tables as pdf or html.

Comment: If this answered your question, you should accept it so that people know it’s been answered

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in